# How to Use Radio Button on Document property page in alfresco

Tags: alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share

I want to use radio buttons on document property page. 
To add checkbox i used below code.

```
<control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/checkbox.ftl">
```

In Above case checkbox.ftl is provided by alfresco. But there is no any RadioButton.ftl available.

So how can i use radio  button on property page?

If any one have achieved this, then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can develop your own control, based on the [Form Control Alfresco documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/dev-extensions-share-form-controls.html).
On this [specific page](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/forms-custom-formcontrol.html), you have more information about the howto.

Finally, I would suggest you to take inspiration from the original **checkbox.ftl** to make your own :

```
<#assign isTrue=false>
<#if field.value??>
 <#if field.value?is_boolean>
    <#assign isTrue=field.value>
 <#elseif field.value?is_string && field.value == "true">
    <#assign isTrue=true>
 </#if>
</#if>

<div class="form-field">
   <#if form.mode == "view">
      <div class="viewmode-field">
         <span class="viewmode-label">${field.label?html}:</span>
         <span class="viewmode-value"><#if isTrue>${msg("form.control.checkbox.yes")}<#else>${msg("form.control.checkbox.no")}</#if></span>
      </div>
   <#else>
      <input id="${fieldHtmlId}" type="hidden" name="${field.name}" value="<#if isTrue>true<#else>false</#if>" />
      <input class="formsCheckBox" id="${fieldHtmlId}-entry" type="checkbox" tabindex="0" name="-" <#if field.description??>title="${field.description}"</#if>
             <#if isTrue> value="true" checked="checked"</#if> 
             <#if field.disabled && !(field.control.params.forceEditable?? && field.control.params.forceEditable == "true")>disabled="true"</#if> 
             <#if field.control.params.styleClass??>class="${field.control.params.styleClass}"</#if>
             <#if field.control.params.style??>style="${field.control.params.style}"</#if> 
             onchange='javascript:YAHOO.util.Dom.get("${fieldHtmlId}").value=YAHOO.util.Dom.get("${fieldHtmlId}-entry").checked;' />
      <label for="${fieldHtmlId}-entry" class="checkbox">${field.label?html}</label>
      <@formLib.renderFieldHelp field=field />
   </#if>
</div>
```